# Only the 1st sentence is displayed after I press the button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

When I press the BUTTON for the 1st time, the label displays "Who's is Arnold?"

When I press the BUTTON for the 2nd time I'd want "Who's is Kevin?" to be displayed on the label field, instead of "Who's is Arnold?"

When I press the button for the 3rd time I'd want "Who's is Liu?" to be displayed on the label field, instead of "Who's is Kevin?"

```
 @IBAction func answerButtonTapped(send: UIButton){ 

   var question = questionField.text 
   var i = 0 


   var listOfQuestions = ["Who is Arnold?", "Who is Kevin?", "Who is Liu?"] 


    for (i=0; i<=listOfQuestions.count; i++){
        questionField.text = "(listOfQuestions[i])"
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised it does't set it to "Who is Liu?" and then crash with an out of range error. If you want to give a different answer button press, you are going to have to retain some state. I'd suggest having a var buttonPresses = 0 as a member variable of your class and then setting questionField.text = listOfQuestions[buttonPresses%listOfQuestions.count] then add 1 to the button presses.

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = 0
var listOfQuestions = ["Who is Arnold?", "Who is Kevin?", "Who is Liu?"]

@IBAction func answerButtonTapped(send: UIButton){ 
  questionField.text = listOfQuestions[counter%listOfQuestions.count] 
  counter++
}
```

Comment: if counter == 500. You'll have case 0 to case 499?

Comment: You'd save code and not throw away information if you used listOfQuestions[counter%listOfQuestions.count) instead, thus avoiding setting counter to 0.

Comment: @GlennHowes what if we want to display the first string after the last most string ?

Comment: @TanguyMP could you accept the answer if nothing wrong with it?

Comment: @hariszaman That's why I put the % (modulus) operator in there, it'll just rotate from 0..2, 0..2 as you add to counter.

Comment: ok thats fine answer updated i thought you were saying to throw away the item from the array

Comment: that's not work  @hariszaman. It sets counter to O, only (Who is Arnold?) is displayed

Comment: could you paste your whole viewcontroller code . I don't see any why the above is not working

Comment: I got it finally, I found this: var currentQuestionIndex = 0

@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    textField.hidden = false
    textField.placeholder = "Country"

    questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]

    if currentQuestionIndex < questions.count {
         ++currentQuestionIndex
         buttonLabel.setTitle("Next", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        (sender as UIButton).userInteractionEnabled = false
    }

}